# Is there something I am doing wrong? I get no errors but no output is displayed

Tags: python, tkinter

For some reason, I am not getting any output when I run nothing happens. I am not sure if I am doing something wrong. What I am trying to do is write a GUI program that converts Celsius to Fahrenheit (Temperature). The formula that I am using is F= 9/5C + 32

```
import tkinter

class TempConverterGUI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.main_window = tkinter.Tk()
        
        self.top_frame = tkinter.Frame()
        self.mid_frame = tkinter.Frame()
        self.bottom_frame = tkinter.Frame()
        
        self.prompt_label = tkinter.Label(self.top_frame, \
                                        text = "Enter a temperature in Celsius: ")
        self.celsius_entry = tkinter.Entry(self.top_frame, width = 10)
        
        self.prompt_label.pack(side= "left")
        self.celsius_entry.pack(side = "left")
        
        self.descr_label = tkinter.Label(self.mid_frame, text = "Converted" + \
                                        "to Fahrenheit: ")
        
        self.value = tkinter.StringVar()
        self.fahrenheit_label = tkinter.Label(self.mid_frame, \
                                             textvariable=self.value)
        
        self.descr_label.pack(side= "left")
        self.fahrenheit_label.pack(side = "left")
        
        
        self.calc_button = tkinter.Button(self.bottom_frame, text = "Convert", \
                                         command= self.convert)
        self.quit_button = tkinter.Button(self.bottom_frame, text = "Quit", \
                                         command= self.main_window.destroy)
        self.calc_button.pack(side= "left")
        self.quit_button.pack(side= "left")
        
        self.top_frame.pack()
        self.mid_frame.pack()
        self.bottom_frame.pack()
        
        tkinter.mainloop()
        
        def convert (self):
            celsius = float(self.celsius_entry.get())
            fahrenheit = format(celsius * 9/5 + 32, ",.1f").rstrip("0").rstrip(".")
            self.value.set(fahrenheit)
            
temp_conv = TempConverterGUI()
```

Comment: Your `__init__` needs 2 underscores on each side, the way it's written now it is not called during initialization.

Comment: then you have some typos like `tkinter.Tk` should be capitalized and `self.promt_label` should have another `p` when assigning it. and `quit_button.pacl` should be `pack`. then I think you're good.

Comment: Thank you for the insight @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen ! I made those corrections, and I am still not receiving any input. What was that comment with calling the main? I don't seem to find that comment any more.

Comment: yes sorry I saw you are calling `tkinter.mainloop()` inside the `__init__` so that should be fine, I meant to edit the comment but hit delete by accident. I was able to get it working.

Comment: is the convert method indented that amount in your code? it should be same indentation as `def __init__` not inside it, maybe that is all you are missing?

Comment: Yes that was it! @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: excellent, glad to help! instead of posting an answer I've just voted to close this as "caused by typo therefore not very helpful to others" since that is kind of the case. (also fewer people downvote closed questions)

Answer (score 0):

The indentation of `convert` method is not correct. It should be on the same level as `__init__` method.

**Like this:**

```
import tkinter


class TempConverterGUI:
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        ...

    def convert(self):
        ...
        ...

temp_conv = TempConverterGUI()
```

**Output:**

[image: GUI output]